# Is there any image recognation gem/ plugin for ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, image-recognition

I wish to detect an image is face or no. as I know there is many cloud API to work this issue, but I wish I can do this from gem/ plugin or something that running on local (no make API request).

So Anyone who already experiences with this hopefully could share. Thanks for your advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried the library myself yet but

https://github.com/jeffrafter/ruby-opencv

has a short example code section on face recognition - although I think this is the source used for the RubyGem OpenCV (or at least a fork of the original), neither has been under development for quite a few years.

http://rubygems.org/gems/opencv

```
gem "opencv", "~> 0.0.7"
```

if you need more up-to-date features maybe try

https://github.com/amarburg/opencv-ffi

Although you will need to import the modules into your public folders (or whichever folder you are using to import external code from - it varies with Rails version), and then follow the example code.

Comment: Hi Pasted, sorry for late reply your post, just open stackoverflow again. thank so much for your suggestion, I already read and try this one, actually still on rolling with this stuf, but I'm still confuse with the example, especially with face detecttor example that what I need https://github.com/ruby-opencv/ruby-opencv/blob/master/examples/face_detect.rb I really have no idea how to try this on (steps). maybe you have any idea to try this example ? thanks

Comment: With the example it's probably best to run it in the interactive console to start with. Make sure that you have the full frontal test xml file in a place you can find on your system. You can find it on the Github site at https://github.com/ruby-opencv/ruby-opencv/blob/master/test/samples/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml.gz. It looks like you may well have to ungzip it (how you do this will depend on what OS you are using).